# Скрипт отображения строк таблицы по select

Tags: javascript

Сейчас у меня на странице работает такой скрипт для скрытия данных таблицы если они не соответствуют введенным данным в поле поиска:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search").keyup(function(){
    _this = this;
    $.each($("#mytable tbody tr"), function() {
      if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1) {
        $(this).hide();
      } else {
        $(this).show();
      }                
    });
  });
});
```

Помогите пожалуйста его переделать так чтобы данные он брал не из текстового поля, а из данных выпадающего списка `<select>`
Например, выбрал "Яблоки" и строки без "Яблоки" скрылись.Я в JS пока полный 0, но очень нужна такая функция для одной задачи. Заранее благодарен за помощь!

Comment: так вы ж фрилансеров на такие задачи натравливайте

Comment: посмотрите про [datelist](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пошарил документации по jQuery событиям и сам нашел решение вопроса, по крайней мере работает так как я хотел, нужно было всего лишь изменить событие:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#esr_list").change(function(){
       _this = this;
       $.each($("#mytable tbody tr"), function() {
           if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1) {
            $(this).hide();
           } else {
            $(this).show();
           }                
       });
    });
});
```